# CompleteableFuture code execution returning error

Tags: java

I'm new to CompleteableFuture and having some issues with this code to work. When attempting the code below I get the Error:(54, 11)

```
java: no suitable method found for supplyAsync(as::address_1)method java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.<U>supplyAsync(java.util.function.Supplier<U>) is not applicable
(cannot infer type-variable(s) U
(argument mismatch; invalid method reference method address_1 in 
class AsyncMain cannot be applied to given types required: java.lang.String found: no arguments

reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
method java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.<U>supplyAsync(java.util.function.Supplier<U>,java.util.concurrent.Executor) is not applicable
(cannot infer type-variable(s) U
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
```

I see the error message is telling me that the method is called for CompletableFuture is incorrect and is looking for a `java.lang.String object` to be present. When I test the main code to execute in-process function I see from simple tests such as `System.out.println(contents.getClass())` that the return output is indeed a string. Any insight is welcomed.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;


public class AsyncMain {
    public String process(String output) throws IOException {
        URL address = new URL("https://api.publicapis.org/random?category=animal");
        InputStreamReader reader = null;
        try {

            reader = new InputStreamReader(address.openStream());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);

        String contents = "";
        String line = "";

        while((line = buffer.readLine()) != null){

            if (line.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
            contents += line;
            //System.out.println(contents);

        }
        return contents;
    }

    public String address_3(String msg) throws IOException {
       return this.process(msg);

    }
    public String address_2(String msg) throws IOException {
        return this.process(msg);

    }

    public String address_1(String msg) throws IOException {
        return this.process(msg);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        AsyncMain as = new AsyncMain();
        CompletableFuture<String> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();

        cf.supplyAsync(as::address_1).thenApply(as::address_2).thenApply(as::address_3);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason for the error is, in the following line,

```
 cf.supplyAsync(as::address_1).thenApply(as::address_2).thenApply(as::address_3);
```

you call method as::address_1 with no arguments, but the method address_1 actually needs a String argument as you already have,

public String address_1(String msg) throws IOException {
    return this.process(msg);

}

you can fix this by changing

```
 public String address_1(String msg) throws IOException {
        return this.process(msg);

    }
```

to

```
 public String address_1() throws IOException {

        return this.process("your_String_input");

    }
```

but since you do not use the String output parameter you can change the code

Comment: Follow up question: I've changed address_1 to be as indicated and no longer get that error message. However, my output is nothing.  Is my main process function failing to return the callback from the URL?

Comment: sorry for being late to be online. Actually, you have to chagne the current code structure to have two process methods, one with no args and one with a String arg

Comment: @Steve i recommended to remove the variable 'String output' because in side the methods it has no usage